# Android Intent Broadcast

Tags: android

I want to create a programme in which an activity is called after 30 seconds of button click. I have user `pendingIntent` and `BroadcastReciever` for that pupose, but nothing is happening. My code is:

```
package com.example.wrox;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmManagerDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,AlarmManagerDemo.class);
        intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "Maza aa  gaya");
        final PendingIntent sender= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast message= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is Starting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                message.show();
                AlarmManager am= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This activity call a Broadcase reciever after 30 seconds of Button click . Code is :

```
package com.example.wrox;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmDemo extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    try{
    Bundle bundle= intent.getExtras();
    String msg= bundle.getString("alarm_message");
    Intent newIntent= new Intent(ctx, NewActivity.class);
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ctx.startActivity(newIntent);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast message= Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        message.show();
    }
}
}
```

This `BroadcastReciever` is calling an activity in which i have used `Toast` to display some static content. But nothing is happening after button click. Please suggest me, where am i making mistake?
No errors and exceptions are generated...

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice resource on [updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html).
Just go into a `Handler` or a `Runnable` when you press the button and sleep for 30 seconds then call upon the `BroadCastReciever`

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the `BroadcastReceiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?